# Flow: Create types from existing types as string literals

Tags: typescript, flowtype

I have a code snippet that works exactly as intended in `TS`, but errors out in `flow`. Is there a way to achieve the same thing in `flow`?

```
type field = 'me' | 'you'
type fieldWithKeyword = `${field}.keyword` //errors out in flow
const appendKeyword = (val:field): fieldWithKeyword => {
    return `${val}.keyword`
}
appendKeyword('me') // works in TS
```

The intention is to create two types, `field` and `fieldWithKeyword`. `fieldWithKeyword` should accept values that are of the form `${field}.keyword` *(in this example, `'me.keyword'` and `'you.keyword'` are the expected values that `fieldWithKeyword` can accept)*

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think something like that is possible in Flow.

From your example you could do it this way:

```
type field = 'me' | 'you'
type fieldWithKeyword = 'me.keyword'|'you.keyword' //errors out in flow
const appendKeyword = (val:field): fieldWithKeyword => {
    return 'me'? 'me.keyword' :'you.keyword';
}
appendKeyword('me')
```

But I guess you wanted something more dynamic, where you don't have to hardcode every string.

Comment: I can do that, but it sort of beats the point tbh. I have a huge collection of fields, and I am hoping to avoid redundancy 

Comment: How are you using the `fieldWithKeyword` strings? Depending of your usage you could create an object

Comment: I am extracting them from a constants object, like `field[fieldName]`, and I want to be able to say `appendKeyword(field[fieldName])` which returns `${field[fieldName]}.keyword`, and to be able to type this.

Comment: My question was more about what do you **do** with `${field[fieldName]}.keyword`

Comment: I am making an API call with it ‍♂️